# I'm trying to share my module but it gives an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-publish

I'm trying to share my module but it gives an error

```
 npm ERR! code E400
    npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/saverdb - deprecations must be strings
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\win10\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-22T17_22_45_529Z-debug.log
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you increment the version number in your package.json, since the last time you published it? (it should be more than `1.0.1`)

Comment: yes i did the version 1.0.2

Comment: Sharing the relevant errors from the logs it mentions may also be helpful if they provide more detail

Comment: Ok, looks like you messed up with the versions haha this is hilarious (click the "versions" tab and "show deprecated versions"): https://www.npmjs.com/package/saverdb You should now publish a version `2.4.8`, or go to `3.0.0` if there are breaking changes

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good :) Sorry I was not mocking you, I just found it funny that NPM allowed lower versions to be published after higher ones. I guess it's for allowing hotfixes on earlier major versions, to avoid forcing users to upgrade, but still provide them fixes